# Why is $f(x)g'(x)+f'(x)g(x)$ a linear map?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Assume $f:E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ and $g:E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and $E \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is open. Assume $x \in E$, and $f$ and $g$ are differentiable at $x$. To get the derivative of $f(x)g(x)$, I get a product rule version, namely $f'(x)g(x)+g'(x)f(x)$.

According to the definition of a derivative (In Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis), $f'(x)g(x)+g'(x)f(x)$ has to be a linear map. But why is it a linear map? Doesn't that imply we need g and f to be linear as well?

Comment: First of all, you need a *sum* in the product rule, not a difference.

Comment: Oh right, thanks! I'll make an edit.

Comment: What is $E$ an open subset of, and What do you think $f'(x)$ is for an $f$ as described? (I think it is a linear map.)

Comment: Sorry yes should've included it in the problem. $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}.$ And $f'(x) \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The derivative of $f$ at $x_0$ is a linear map $A$ such that $f(x) - f(x_0) - A(x-x_0) = o(x-x_0)$ as $x \to x_0$. That linear map is what we call $f'(x_0)$. The actual mapping $x_0 \mapsto f'(x_0)$ is usually not linear.

Now when you look at $fg$, the situation is essentially the same. You get a linear map $A$ such that $f(x) g(x) - f(x_0) g(x_0) - A(x-x_0)=o(x-x_0)$ as $x \to x_0$. The product rule winds up telling you that the linear map is $f'(x_0) g(x_0) + f(x_0) g'(x_0)$. You should try to be careful about signatures to make sure this makes sense: $f'(x_0)$ is a map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $g(x_0)$ is a scalar, so that is the right type of thing (you multiply by $g(x_0)$ after applying $f'(x_0)$ to the input). Now $f(x_0)$ is a fixed vector in $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $g'(x_0)$ is a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$, so that is also the right type of thing (you multiply by $f(x_0)$ after applying $g'(x_0)$ to the input).

Comment: Why is $f'(x_0)g(x_0)+f(x_0)g'(x_0)$ a linear map though? More specifically why does the linearity property follow, i.e. is $f'(x+h)g(x+h) + f(x+h)g'(x+h)$ $=f'(x)g(x)+g'(x)f(x)+f(h)g'(h)+f'(h)g(h)$?

Comment: @platypus17 It isn't linear as a function of $x_0$. It is linear as a function of the implicit vector argument.

Comment: ohh I think I see it now, ok thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To sort this out more carefully, let's consider the derivative at a point $x$ in the direction $v\in\Bbb R^n$. Then $g(x)\big(f'(x)v\big)$ is the product of a scalar with a vector in $\Bbb R^m$. Similarly, $\big(g'(x)v\big)f(x)$ is the product of a scalar with a vector in $\Bbb R^m$. Both expressions are linear in $v$, so we end up with a linear map from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R^m$.

Comment: Why is $f(x)$ a scalar? Isn't $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}^m$? Or is there like a "dot product" version of scaling being used here? @Ted Shifrin

Comment: $f(x) g'(x)$ is actually the product of a fixed vector and a linear functional, where the latter term means a scalar-valued linear map.

Comment: Yes, my original answer was sloppy and wrong. My apologies. See if what I've edited makes more sense.

Comment: Is $f(x)g'(x)$ technically a linear map? Since it's multiplying by a fixed vector, not a scalar.

Comment: It's the product of vector in $\Bbb R^m$ with a linear map from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R$; as a matrix, it's the product of an $m\times 1$ matrix and a $1\times n$ matrix.